# display image from url in rounded imageview android

Tags: android

I want to display my images in listview where the imageview is rounded, i serached in the net and in stackoverflow i just found that they use bitmap or i dont like to use it because i'm getting my information from webservice. is there any method or exemple to display it in this way.

this is how i display my images rectangle border

```
mLoader.DisplayImage(mylink + ArrayListComment.get(position).getImage(), holder.imageView);
        }
    if(ArrayListComment.get(position).getImage().contains(".png") {

        mLoader.DisplayImage(ArrayListComment.get(position).getImage(), holder.imageView);
    }
```

Comment: There are various library available in GitHub check out : https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView or https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rounded ImageView use [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView).

For display image from url use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new **rounded.xml** under drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#FFffffff" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#FFffffff" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and use it in your xml image view like this:
`android:src="@drawable/rounded"` and set the image background as you want it to be, it will be in a rounded shape

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;

public class ImageHelper {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

You will have to customise your image loader.

EDIT:

If you dont want to create a copy of a bitmap, you can use a bitmap shader.

See this blog,

http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

See the [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) for implementation.

Comment: i don't want to use bitmap because getting data from webservice will be heavy

Comment: So you want to create a custom `ImageView` with round shape?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can od it by customizing your Imageview. Please  check out my customImageview class Which may help you.enter code here.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    int w = getWidth();
    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
            sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

## Try this link

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {

```
Bitmap sbmp;
if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
    sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
else
    sbmp = bmp;
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
        sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xffa19774;

final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));

canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
        sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


        return output;
```

}

http://easyandroidexample.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-make-image-circle-view.html

may it work for you